# How can I count and remove all of the mobs of a specific type on a bukkit server?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have 2900 passive mobs according to the entity suppressor plugin, and I would like to know how many of each kind has spawned. Hopefully that will help prevent this from happening again. =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [EntityPolice](http://dev.bukkit.org/server-mods/entitypolice/) Bukkit plugin:

```
/entitypolice count cow
> 649
```